# Ошибка при установке laravel

Tags: php, laravel

При установке Laravel я получаю "oops< something went wrong" и след. текст ошибки. В чем проблема? Не могу разобраться.

```
 in Encrypter.php line 43
at Encrypter->__construct('', 'AES-256-CBC') in EncryptionServiceProvider.php line 27
at EncryptionServiceProvider->Illuminate\Encryption\{closure}(object(Application)) in Container.php line 678
at Container->build(object(Closure)) in Container.php line 565
at Container->make('encrypter') in Application.php line 702
at Application->make('Illuminate\\Contracts\\Encryption\\Encrypter') in Container.php line 771
at Container->resolveClass(object(ReflectionParameter)) in Container.php line 733
at Container->resolveDependencies(array(object(ReflectionParameter))) in Container.php line 710
at Container->build('App\\Http\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies') in Container.php line 565
at Container->make('App\\Http\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies') in Application.php line 702
at Application->make('App\\Http\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies') in Pipeline.php line 138
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 561
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 520
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 498
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 174
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 30
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in TransformsRequest.php line 30
at TransformsRequest->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in TransformsRequest.php line 30
at TransformsRequest->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ValidatePostSize.php line 27
at ValidatePostSize->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 46
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 149
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 116
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 5
```

4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выполните команду `php artisan key:generate` чтобы сгенерировать `APP_KEY`, либо сами его пропишите в `.env` файле.

Comment: Кажется, в некоторых версиях название команды отличается

Comment: Спасибо! Нужно мне было внимательнее документацию читать.